# Simple, Cheap, and Poor Quality Audio Amp

Tags: audio, amplifier, bjt

So I am attempting to build/design a audio amp. Basically around a 1 watt amp for a walkie-talkie. I'm planning to run it off a 9V battery. When thinking about a power amp several ideas came to mind. I looked online and found the same several different designs. So in trying to avoid comparing a lot of designs I thought I would ask for some opinions. I picked my top 4 and I would like to hear some thoughts on which if any is the best route per the specs.

Specs: 
Has to be loud - (Circuit has to be able to realize the needed gain) and output 1W
low/no current draw when no input signal - turned off (can use additional circuitry)
Max VCC:  9V(No current constraint yet)
As cheap as possible/or as few components (most important)

Additional Notes:
The quality of the sound needs to be decent/understandable - walkie-talkie quality - not for music

Design 1:

[image]

Design 2:

[image]

Design 3:

[image]

Design 4: My pick so far!

[image]

Comment: I believe that all of these are Class A amplifiers, which means that they will draw a great deal of current even when no input signal is present. Also, I think the biasing network should be connect directly to the 9V supply rather than the Darlington's collector.

Comment: @JoeHass yes I could rig up a simple circuit to cut the power though since I already have means of detecting a input. This would add a components though. Thanks!

Comment: "Has to be loud - on the order of 80db" - how many anomalies here - 80 dB what? How loud is your loudspeaker (and don't say it's X watts)?

Comment: @Andyaka I was referencing 80dB as the Sound Pressure Level. Im not sure what your asking beyond 8ohm 1W speaker

Comment: An amplifier is like a car without wheels. The wheels are like the loudspeaker. Not all wheels can go fast and not all speakers are loud as each other - they have different SPL outputs for the same input power. So, getting back to my question, if you want 80dB SPL, what does the data sheet for the speaker say that it needs in terms of voltage at 1kHz?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm going to assume your reading into the problem incorrectly. All that statement was implying is that I need to be able to control the gain. Im just starting this project and set some pecs to just help myself in picking a design. Sure this plays a part but all I meant by this was that I need to be able to adjust the gain so that this is obtainable. I have yet to pick any components. This is merely looking at the different configurations.

Comment: @tman I wasn't born yesterday dude. Gain has nothing to do with SPL.

Comment: @Andyaka you asked, "So, getting back to my question, if you want 80dB SPL, what does the data sheet for the speaker say that it needs in terms of voltage at 1kHz?". How can you ask what voltage the speaker needs and not relate this to gain. The output voltage is adjustable per the chosen gain. Is your claim that its impossible to pick a design without knowledge of the speaker to be used? If so then advise this.

Comment: If you want 80 dB SPL then the speaker spec will inform you what voltage needs to be applied to the speaker terminals to achieve this - it might say 94dB SPL at such and such a voltage and, from that you can infer what the voltage will be to achieve 80 dB SPL. At no time has gain of the amplifier come into this at all - in fact it has nothing to do with amplifier gain.

Comment: @Andyaka so you're implying that I can't possibly pick a circuit design without choosing a speaker first!

Comment: Listen I'm getting bored of this so take a look at this device http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa4861.pdf it's a 1 watt amplifier with shutdown control so you can disable it when there is no signal. It runs from 5V so you should consider a voltage regulator. Also take a look at all the TI can offer here: http://www.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?familyId=1974&sectionId=630&tabId=2701&family=analog&uiTemplateId=AUDIO_PRDSRCH_T#p342=0.35;1

Comment: And yes, without picking a speaker you can't theoretically know how much voltage to drive it with to get 80 dB SPL. Just because a speaker says it is 1 watt doesn't mean it produces 1 watt of audible output. End of.

Comment: @Andyaka great picks except 8 times more expensive. I asked a simple question to look at the circuits i provided and give feedback as to why or why not...Thanks for your input!

Comment: Ok, ignoring your sarcasm, as already pointed out to you, these are class A amplifiers and this means they are no more than 50% power efficient. This in turn means they are not capable of driving 1 watt into 8 ohms from a 9v supply. You need 8v peak to peak to do this and none of the above are realistically capable of achieving that. Now settle down, stop being sarcastic and listen to what people can tell you.

Comment: Consider Olin's cct or similar. Of your ccts only 3 has any real hope. The others pass large DC through the speaker, which it will not like. Note that Pwr = V^2/R. For a 9V supply with full swiung Vpkmax = +/- 4.5V or RMS = 0.707 x this = ~= 3.2V. So with rail-rail swing Pmax =~ 1.25W. Drop a small amount of either swing extent and you are < 1W. As Olin notes.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I agree if the 1 watt was the most important spec, but my aim is truly as few/cheap as components as i can. I would have already used an Audio Power Amplifier if that was not the case. My specs are rough at this point and i am merely trying to pick the best circuit to give myself the best chance at achieving the desired results. Thanks

Comment: @tman: You now say fewest components is the priority, but give no justification for that. You might have a limited board area budget, or cost, but number of components doesn't make sense. That is in part why you're not getting answers you want. Tell use the *real* criteria, and leave your supposed solutions out of it. They largely don't make sense either. It's easier to give you ideas than spend time having to debunk something you dreamed up or found on then internet somewhere.

Comment: As Olin says - you need to REALLY define what you actually want. You mention few components and cost. Cost of a 1 off doesn't **usually**  matter vastly if it's not over a few dollars. If it's intended for volume production then China sourced parts cost close to zero - eg LM386 probably under 10 cents. | An LM324 + a jelly bean PNP/NPN at output will do most of what you want at low cost. Again - cheap in one off and very cheap in China volume. | Why not tell us what you are REALLY trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You have several conflicting requirements.  First let's look at what real specs you did provide.  You have power available at 9 V, and you want to put 1 W into a 8 Ω speaker.  That requires 2.83 V RMS, which is 8 V peak to peak.  That means you only have 500 mV headroom at each end given the 9 V supply, at least if you want to keep the circuit "simple".

1 W into 8 Ω given 9 V power is not really all that "simple", considering that the power stage has to be able to drive to within 1/2 V of the rails and then source or sink 1/2 A when doing that.

Since "simple" is a meaningless spec anyway, we'll ignore that and work with the real specs you provided.  Here is a topology that comes to mind:

[image]

This is just the power stage, which is the tricky part.  This power stage has a voltage gain of about 2, and input impedance of about 1 kΩ  That's not too hard for a simple gain stage to drive.  That gain stage only needs to swing about half the supply voltage, and the relatively high impedance leaves open a lot of options.

However, if I was doing this I'd ditch all this and use a off the shelf class D audio amplifier chip.

Comment: Interesting. What's C2 for? Why wouldn't you just ground that junction? Is it a zero?

Comment: @EJP C2 is for an AC connection between the point where R5, R6 are connected and the ground. It could be DC-connected to a midpoint between the power rails, but we don't have one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The 1 watt was me trying to get something on the drawing board for getting started. I am really interested in trying to pull this off with as few components as necessary. Looking at the designs I suggested and delving into the a bit farther: I think that the design 3 would allow me the best chance of yielding the desired results. I found a 1 watt darlington pair but with the circuit in Design 4 I'm doubtful I will get anywhere close to an amp. I just thought id ask if you could elaborate more on the designs I suggested given the specs are just targets and not musts.

Comment: @tman: Design 3 doesn't look like a good idea. Whether it meets your goals is now impossible to say since we can't tell what the real specs are anymore. Thanks for the wild goose chase.  I'll try to remember to take anything you say in the future less seriously and not spend much time on it.

Comment: Wow. I thought this might me a good place to bounce ideas around and not be hit with such negativity. When I start a project were I pick the specs they are typically goals..sometimes achievable other times not. My question clearly stated, " I picked my top 4 and I would like to hear some thoughts on which if any is the best route per the specs." The specs were goals, but I wanted to at the minimum as few components as necessary. Sorry for giving you a bad impression. I am sure my question asking could obviously improve, and I am sorry you feel the way you do. Have a good day.